# Linked lists, arrays, and hardware memory caches

Tags: arrays, performance, linked-list, language-agnostic, cpu-cache

While questions have been asked before about linked lists versus arrays, the answers mostly boil down to what most of us probably have already learned at some point:

- Lists are good at inserting and deleting
- Arrays are good at random access

Now respectable people like Bjarne Stroustrup have [argued](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo) that arrays practically always outperform linked lists because they make much better use of the caching architecture implemented in modern hardware. He also states that the performance advantage of arrays increases with their size.

While I basically understand his arguments and agree with him, I wonder if this is still true when the size of the array is significantly larger than cache size. I would say that this is the case where performance really matters.

To summarize: **Do arrays still perform better than lists in most cases, even if their size is much larger than cache size and a large percentage of the operations are inserts or deletes? If yes, how can this be explained?**

Comment: CPU caches load data in chunks of sequential addresses, so for sequential access producing one miss, several subsequent reads will hit cache. For linked list this does't work. See http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/

Comment: @VictorSorokin: Yes, I understand that caching is of little or no use for linked list performance, but that was not my question. I also understand that read and write of sequential array elements will highly benefit from caching, even if the array is larger than the cache, but what about insert and delete?

Comment: Actually, link example 2/3 explanations and results are confusing to me, I've tried to reproduce them, but failed. That said, general idea still applies. Regarding insertions/deletions -- if your app dominated by them, you'll benefit from lists surely. Another approach, 'best of two worlds', is to have writers operate on LLs and copy data to array for (sequential) readers.

Comment: @VictorSorokin: I assume that you have tried to reproduce it with Java (after looking at your profile) while Stroustrup talks about C++. Actually I thought the effect should not strongly depend on the language, but maybe that was wrong. I will do some investigations myself as soon as I find the time.

Comment: Plain C, sir: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e326bc9b764e3f04c494a213f704a669

Comment: @VictorSorokin: Thanks, but this example only seems to check array read/write performance for different index increments. Neither does it compare this with linked lists nor does it check insert/delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays perform better not only because of caching, but also because of prefetching.

Caching has 2 main benefits - sequential elements may reside in the same line, so you may fetch once and use the entire line multiple times (while in a linked list your next element is elsewhere so you don't enjoy the benefit). This benefit is reduced the bigger the elements become, and is gone once your element passes a line size.

The second benefit is more subtle - you get better utilization of the cache since it's organized in a way that benefits sequential allocation. This means that an array up to the cache size may still fit, while a randomly allocated list may have some collisions that would cause thrashing even if the list size is smaller than the cache.

However, aside from caching, the bigger benefit from spatially allocated structures is from prefetching. Most CPUs would automatically prefetch the next lines in a stream of accesses such as an array access, and would therefore eliminate all misses in a scenario of sequential access.

On the other hand, all these benefits are just optimizations, so they can only speed up the performance linearly, but can never mitigate an asymptotic complexity difference such as the O(1) insertion that the list provides. Eventually, you will need to benchmark your code to see if such cases are required and create a bottleneck - if so, a hybrid approach may be needed.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the additional aspects of prefetching and asymptotic complexity. However, O(1) complexity of insertion into a list presumes that the insertion node is already known. Stroustrup argues that in practice, this is usually not the case. Instead you first have to do a O(n) search for the node.

Comment: Good point, so let's say complexity-wise we're at O(n) for both. But arrays and lists are fundamentally different data structures with different use cases. Instead, think of a graph that can be implemented either as a linked structure of vertices/edges, or as a matrix (sparse, most likely). Which method will be easier to manipulate (say it's a tree and you want to perform AVL rolls)? And which will be easier for the programmer and less bug prone?